# Merge list in multiple columns to a single column in pandas

Tags: pandas, list, merge

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format:

```
           0           1        2           3
A.pkl     [121,122]   [123]    [124,125]    [126,127]
```

The number of columns might be more as well. In the end, I would like to merge all the values in all the columns and write it to a single column.

Result dataframe:

```
           values          
A.pkl     [121,122,123,124,125,126,127]
```

I use the below code to generate the first part:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
g: pd.read_pickle(f'{g}')['values'].tolist()
for g in groups
}).T
```

I tried using itertools.chain but it doesnt seem to do the trick.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Input dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['aa.pkl'],
               '0': [["001A000001", "003A0025"]],
               '1': [["003B000001","003C000001"]],
               '2': [["003D000001", "003E000001"]],
               '3': [["003F000001", "003G000001"]]})
```

The above dataframe is generated in the by reading the pickle file

Comment: `df.sum(axis=1)` seems to work fine.

Comment: @QuangHoang: could not do it for the series object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `itertools.chain` is one way to go, but you have to do it properly:

```
from itertools import chain
df.apply(lambda x: list(chain(*x)), axis=1)
```

output:

```
A.pkl    [121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127]
dtype: object
```

As @QuangHoang suggested you can also use the `df.sum(axis=1)` trick, but be careful, this only works with lists. If for some reason you have numpy arrays this will perform the sum per position (`[494, 497]`).

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [[121, 122]],
                   '1': [[123]],
                   '2': [[124, 125]],
                   '3': [[126, 127]]})
```

Comment: It throws an error with axis=1 in lambda function. I used this:  g: pd.read_pickle(f'{g}')['cluster'].apply(lambda x: list(chain(*x)), axis=1)

Comment: can you provide your input dataframe as dataframe constructor or dictionary (`df.to_dict('list')`)? (see my update)

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: @user3447653 I see, you should exclude 'name' from the chaining, set it as index: `df.set_index('name').apply(lambda x: list(chain(*x)), axis=1)`